How can you dynamically change favicon on tab switch in wordpress
I'm trying to change the favicon in wordpress but it doesn't work
I saw people do it by using javascript but I don't know how to do it on wordpress. I'm kinda new to web design and i can only do it by using wordpress. I'm practicing in xampp.
I saw some website they can change the favicon while switching tab. Sorry for my English.

You can just go to customiser in your dashboard and change the favicon with another image. But if you want to change with javascript you can check this answer in this link. Indeed the url link.href in the answer has to be cahnged to your image path

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To change the favicon, you don't need any use of javascript, simple go to Appearance-> Customize. There you will find option of Site logo and tagline, in this section, there is option to change the favicon for your website.

The OP wants to change the favicon when the browser tab is switched (ex: unfocused).

// Add this script to the footer or header of your WordPress theme.
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
if (document.hidden) {
changeFavicon('/path-to-your-hidden-favicon.ico');
} else {
changeFavicon('/path-to-your-original-favicon.ico');
}
});
function changeFavicon(src) {
var link = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");
if (!link) {
link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'icon';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}
link.href = src;
}
